# Improve server response time

Tags: php, html, css, performance, wordpress

So I'm using a wordpress theme but it's kinda slow so when I opened my chrome inspecter I saw this for the main request(sitename.com/)

[image]

The wordpress site runs on my localhost, from where I should start debugging or what tools should I use?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that it's your theme? Is it faster with a different theme? Wordpress is quite slow by itself. Have you configured proper caching?

Comment: I don't have any caching since I'm the only one on the website!

Comment: Is it faster with a different theme?

Comment: how large is the file?

Comment: @Dagon Does that matter much when running on local machine?

Comment: @Dagon Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Dagon 191 requests  ❘  376 KB transferred  ❘  11.17 s (onload: 9.86 s, DOMContentLoaded: 7.83 s)

Comment: ouch, and that's local, wait till its hosted somewhere, you need to trim that. 191 requests for 1 page!

Comment: This may help: http://gomakethings.com/high-performance-websites/

Answer (score 1):

Use `Xdebug` extension for apache server,

http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Answer (score 0):

try plugin performance profiler: http://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/
and definitely use caching; super cache and hyper cace are simple to configure. If you're concerned about overhead, hyper cache has almost none. It only caches a page when it's visited the first time & does not 'preload' the cache like super cache or w3 total cache.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to PHP 5.5 with the Opcache extension enabled should give you a ~400% speed improvement for Wordpress. Unless external resources are involved, of course.